# isFirstRun AS3 Air applicationUpdaterUI

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to make an updater that auto checks for an update, then auto downloads and installs, then after it's installed checks for a First Run event. I want this so I can reset a trial version of the software when anyone downloads the new version.

I had the autoupdate working, but messed it up somewhere. I don't understand the order of operations here especially for the initialize() method. In the API it shows a isFirstRun boolean which means it's checking after everything has already been downloaded and installed I would think. Any suggestions on making this work...first to get it to download an update and to get the isFirstRun boolean to TRUE

```
import air.update.ApplicationUpdaterUI;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import air.update.events.StatusUpdateEvent;
import air.update.events.*;

var appWindow:NativeWindow = this.stage.nativeWindow;
//Code for making Dialog Boxes---from http://thirdroute.com/2011/12/native-alerts-in-air/  AND http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2012/03/simple-way-to-get-native-alerts-with-adobe-air/
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
var alertDispatcher:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
var _html:String ="<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'>" +
                    "<title></title><script></script></head><body></body></html>";
alertDispatcher.loadString(_html); //End of Code for Dialog Boxes.

var appUpdater:ApplicationUpdaterUI = new ApplicationUpdaterUI(); 
appUpdater.updateURL = "http://www.postureviewer.com/update/updateDescriptor.xml" ;
appUpdater.delay = 0;
appUpdater.initialize();
appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false;

versionNumberTxt.text = appUpdater.currentVersion;

appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, appUpdaterComplete);
appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);

function appUpdaterComplete(e:UpdateEvent) {
    appUpdater.checkNow();
    if (appUpdater.isFirstRun) {
        alertDispatcher.window.alert("First Run");
    } else {
        alertDispatcher.window.alert("No...Not First Run");
    }
}
function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    alertDispatcher.window.alert("Error: "+event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the position of the event listeners and got rid of the else part of the if statement. Now it works. The part that confused me as well was when the INITIALIZED event fired. It fires once when it's just about to update and fires again after the update is all finished and restarts the air program. It's this second time that I'm interested in capturing the "isFirstRun" event. I don't want it to let me know it's not a first run at all.

```
import air.update.ApplicationUpdaterUI;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import air.update.events.StatusUpdateEvent;
import air.update.events.*;

var appWindow:NativeWindow = this.stage.nativeWindow;
//Code for making Dialog Boxes---from http://thirdroute.com/2011/12/native-alerts-in-air/  AND http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2012/03/simple-way-to-get-native-alerts-with-adobe-air/
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
var alertDispatcher:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
var _html:String ="<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'>" +
                    "<title></title><script></script></head><body></body></html>";
alertDispatcher.loadString(_html); //End of Code for Dialog Boxes.

var appUpdater:ApplicationUpdaterUI = new ApplicationUpdaterUI(); 
appUpdater.updateURL = "http://www.postureviewer.com/update/updateDescriptor.xml" ;
appUpdater.delay = 0;
appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, appUpdaterComplete);
appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);

appUpdater.initialize();
appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false;

versionNumberTxt.text = appUpdater.currentVersion;

function appUpdaterComplete(e:UpdateEvent) {
    appUpdater.checkNow();
    if (appUpdater.isFirstRun) {    //This only evaluates to true after an update has occurred...
        alertDispatcher.window.alert("First Run");
    }
}
function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    alertDispatcher.window.alert("Error: "+event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing a trial with specified number of permissible runs before expiry, then you could reset, on completion, the user's available number of trial runs back to 0, or if continuing, by adding the number of trial runs already used. Similarly for permitted number of days, date, etc.

Comment: I have the whole trial thing figured out, but I need to reset it when the application is updated and is first run. What's wrong with the code above and is my 'if' statement in the correct place...meaning is it in the right event --> the INITIALIZED event?

Comment: Have you tried UpdateEvent.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE event instead?